# Send email with sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin on symfony framework

Tags: plugins, symfony1, logging, swiftmailer

I'd installed sfDoctrineGuardPlugin & sfForkedDoctrineApplyPlugin on my symfony app.

When i try to signup a new account, its seems to works because : i have this message which appears :

> "Thank you for applying for an account. You will receive a verification email shortly. If you do not see that email, please be sure to check your "spam" or "bulk" folder."

But i have no mail in my mailbox.

And when i look to the logs files, i can see this :

> sfMailerMessageLoggerPlugin    Sending email "Please verify your account on MYPROJECT" to "email@test.com"

Informations : this is my factories.yml's file :

```
  mailer:
    class: sfMailer
    param:
      logging:           %SF_LOGGING_ENABLED%
      charset:           %SF_CHARSET%
      delivery_strategy: realtime
      transport:
        class: Swift_SmtpTransport
        param:
          host:       smtp.gmail.com
          port:       465
          encryption: ssl
          username:   email@gmail.com
          password:   password
```

I'm using my app in localhost. The ssl extension is activated on php.ini

Can you help me please ? And sorry for my bad english!

---

Comment: If you try sending an email from your app, does it work? Is the sfApplyPlugin section in your app.yml correct?

Comment: It is important to set the 'From' header of your mail message to be exactly what your gmail address is, otherwise GMail will not allow the message to pass through.

Comment: Gmail will let it through, but will overwrite the From field to your gmail account.

Answer (score 0):

check that this lines are not present in factories.yml:

```
dev:
  mailer:
    param:
      delivery_strategy: none
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's right, this lines are present in my factories.yml file.
I deleted this lines and it solves my problem.

"dev" configuration is priority to "all" configuration.

Thanks you, and sorry form my bad english.